# What is this C++ casting code doing?

Tags: c++, casting, semantics

Found here: https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/blob/master/src/BRepAdaptor/BRepAdaptor_Curve.cxx

The line I'm wondering about is:

`((GeomAdaptor_Curve*) (void*) &myCurve)->Load(C,First,Last);`

`myCurve` is already defined as a `GeomAdaptor_Curve`.  So it looks like it's casting a pointer to `myCurve` as a `void*`, and then casting *that* as a `GeomAdaptor_Curve*`, and then dereferencing it and calling `Load` on it.  What possible reason could there be for doing that, rather than simply calling `myCurve.Load`?

Comment: Legacy code most probably, time before could be of another type that need to be cast to `GeomAdaptor_Curve`, but it's really strange the double cast, if there where pointer arithmetic involved, would be less strange. All before `->` it's really odd.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason now. Other methods in that same class just call `myCurve.Load()` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that statement appears in a `const` member function.  So the type of `&myCurve` is actually `GeomAdaptor_Curve const*`.  This appears to be an ugly and confusing way to say

```
const_cast<GeomAdaptor_Curve&>(myCurve).Load(C,First,Last);
```

and may have been made more complicated in order to "avoid" compiler warnings you would get from attempting to use a C-style cast to circumvent `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could think of would be to ensure that a variable of the type "subclass of `GeomAdaptor_Curve`" was forced to call the `Load` function of the super-class.

The cast to `void*`, then on to `GeomAdaptor_Curve*`, would guarantee the type was treated as the latter, regardless of its actual type.

Having looked into the code, I can't see where this is a possibility so it's likely that it's either legacy code or something they've put in for future expansion.

It may be worthwhile contacting the `dbarbier` user on GitHub as they appear to have sole responsibility for changes (based on history).

Although, since that piece of code seems to be in the earliest GitHub versions, the original author may be a better bet, if you can find them (see the file header for one Remi LEQUETTE).

Comment: I checked the repo, and just as OP says. `myCurve` is already just the type of `GeomAdaptor_Curve`. Not subclass nor superclass. I prefer to think that this cast is just an unnecessary legacy code.